# Simulate mouse left bottom and right bottom

Tags: winapi, mouseevent, mouse, simulation

I want to simulate mouse movement, but not just one way. I need my mouse to go to the bottom left, then go to the bottom right, then finally go back to the bottom left again.

1. bottom left, 2 seconds
2. bottom right, 2 seconds
3. bottom left again, 2 seconds

But I can't make it work. What do I need to do? Is this possible?

If we can not do all three; we can do first 2. i.e. only bottom left 2 sec then bottom right 2 sec.

I have this in `ahk` but its only one way, always going to the left bottom. I need it in `C++`.

```
    #NoEnv
SendMode Input

~F6::Suspend
~End::ExitApp
~F5::Reload

LCtrl & ~LButton::
Loop
    If GetKeyState("LButton", "LCtrl") {
        Sleep, 3
        moveAmount := (moveAmount = 0.2) ? 3 : -1
        mouseXY(moveAmount,2)
    }
    else
    break

~LButton::
Loop
    If GetKeyState("LButton") {
        Sleep, 3
        moveAmount := (moveAmount = 0.2) ? 3 : -1
        mouseXY(moveAmount,2)
    }
    else
    break

Return



mouseXY(x,y)
{
DllCall("mouse_event",int,1,int,x,int,y,uint,0,uint,0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx), not `GetKeyState`.  `GetKeyState` returns the value captured when the last message was dispatched.

Also, check out [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) on MSDN.  `mouse_event` has long been deprecated.

And please, add tag 'winapi' to your question.

Comment: In this particular case, where you need to inject single mouse move events, separated by a delay, there is nothing to be gained from using `SendInput` over `mouse_event`.

Comment: @IInspectable But you may as well use the non deprecated function if you are starting from scratch

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `mouse_event` has not been deprecated. It has been superseded by `SendInput`. Sure, using `SendInput` doesn't hurt. But I was commenting on this answer that suggests, that using `mouse_event` were somehow wrong, which it isn't. If it recommends using a different API call, it should at least explain, why.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) says "This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead."  So if it says don't use it, don't use it.  I don't know why we're even discussing this,